# Line ends in circuitikz not working

Tags: circuitikz

How do I fix the line ends drawn with `circuitikz`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,european]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]

\begin{document}
\small
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0)node[anchor=east] {(0,0)}to [L,o-o]++(2,0) node(a){}node[anchor=west] {a};

\draw (0,0) |- (1,1);
\draw (a) |- (1,1);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a blank node superposed with the right pole, `node(a){}`, which has a non-zero size; you are connecting to its border. Look at the first FAQ in the `circuitikz` manual. You can "fix" it by using `coordinate(a)`, but Zarko's solution is better.

Comment: If I use `coordinate(a)` 6.1.1 Transparent poles says:  This is because, for simplicity of operation, the nodes are placed after the wires are drawn and have to “white-out” the underlying lines.  So is the wire at (0,0) a bug?

Comment: Are `|-` and `-|` wires drawn after the poles?

Comment: The poles are drawn after the lines *in the same path*. You have three paths here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, with the last comment, now I understand your problem.

Nodes are drawn after the lines *in the same path*. In your example you have three different paths, that are drawn in order.

So you probably (apart from the problem with the `node` → `coordinate thing`) want just one path here:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)node[anchor=east] {(0,0)} 
        to [L,o-o]++(2,0) coordinate(a){}
        node[anchor=west] {a}
    (0,0) |- (1,1)
    (a) |- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/729

Answer (score 2):

It is nor entirely clear what you like to fix so I only guess that you may be after the following:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,european]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]

\begin{document}
\small
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) coordinate[label=left:{(0,0)}] (x) to [L] ++(2,0) coordinate[label=right:a] (a)
      (x) to [short, o-] ++ (0,1) -- ++ (2,0) to [short,-o] (a);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create a named `ocirc` node, lines will automatically be drawn to the edges, so long as you use the name and not the center coordinates.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,european]{circuitikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]% redundant in standalone

\begin{document}
\small
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0)node[left] {(0,0)}
   node[ocirc,name=o]{} to [L] ++(2,0) node[ocirc,name=a]{}
   node[right] {a};

\draw (o) |- (1,1);
\draw (a) |- (1,1);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, you're right! (But also `node[ocirc](a){}` works, I think...). This work if you have a reasonably new version of `circuitikz` (I added the border anchors for all nodes in 0.9.2)

Comment: Oops, I was adding (a) after {}.  That would never work.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, but without node.

```
   \documentclass\[border=3mm\]{standalone}
    \usepackage\[cuteinductor\]{circuitikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0)node\[left\] {(0,0)}--++(0,1)--++(2,0)--++(0,-1)node\[right\]{(2,0)};
    \draw (0,0)to\[L,o-o\](2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, fixing the issue by doing the wires first!